# UIViewController as Subclass of another UIViewController

Tags: swift

[image]I have five tabbar items in my tab bar. The fifth item is popup ViewController. So when I click that button a popup will be shown in the current controller. I am using UIViewController as a subclass to achieve this.

My problem is if I add a popup ViewController in FirstTabItem and moved to SecondTabItem. Then if I am again Click the FirstTabItem the popup ViewController only display and current ViewController is hidden. Here is my code.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
        navigationController.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0 is MoreViewController }) {

        let vc = MoreView(nibName: "MoreView", bundle: nil)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return false
    } else  {
        return true
    }
}

    extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }

    return viewController
}
```

}

Comment: When you say popup VC, what do you mean exactly?  It is a VC pushed on a navigation controller?  Is it a popover?

Comment: This code you are showing is unusual because you are changing the VC hierarchy in a function that is just supposed to return true/false (not change things)  -- it's hard to know how to help -- are there other places you are presenting/pushing/popping/dismissing?

Comment: I tried to guess what is wrong, but to understand your app, we need to understand the VC hierarchy you are building (the NavControllers, Tabs, what is in the tabs -- for example, are there more NavControllers?) and be precise in the explanation -- the exact UIViewController name you are using and the type of presentation exactly.

Comment: Hi i have update the code. I have xib file. I want to add this xib as a popover view to other UIViewControllers. This will happen when click fifth tab bar items. I create separate UIViewController class for this xib file.

Comment: Hi, This is my design. Fifth one is the popover view. I have create a xib for this. Now I returned false coz when click the fifth tab item it should not navigate to next view controller. I should show this xib in current ViewController.

Comment: ok, when you hit the 5th one, what does you code above do?

Answer (score 0):

You have code

```
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present ....
```

If that is the one you want to dismiss, you have to dismiss from the same view controller that presented

```
UIApplication.topViewController()?.dismiss...
```

Generally you would not want to do all of that code in this function -- it's supposed to be just returning a Bool, not changing the view hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, See my design. I am trying to acheive this. More tab  is a xib file. when click that tab item I have to show this xib file as a popover view in currently visible ViewController. Is there any way to do this?